# qmlscene: not able to find custom package : module not installed

Tags: qml

I have a bunch of QML files packaged together to form 'CommonControls' custom package.
I used the Items from the 'CommonControls' to develop another QML files using "import CommonControls 1.0" statement.

Using 'qmlscene' I want to run the developed QML files but its not able to find 'CommonControls' package.

Used following options to resolve the dependency but failed

1. > qmlscene  DashboardViewFunctionBar.qml
   >   error:> file:///C:/Bin/Views/Base/DashboardView.qml:2 module "CommonControls" is not installed
2. using '-I' import option

   > qmlscene -I ......\Bin\CommonControls DashboardView.qml
   >   error:> file:///C:/Bin/Views/Base/DashboardView.qml:2 module "CommonControls" is not installed
3. using '-I' with absolute path

   > qmlscene -I C:\Bin\CommonControls DashboardView.qml
   >   error:> file:///C:/Bin/Views/Base/DashboardView.qml:2 module "CommonControls" is not installed

What am I missing here ?

Comment: If you're importing "CommonControls", then you should probably pass the folder that contains CommonControls as a subfolder, instead of the CommonControls folder itself.

Comment: That worked !
thanks